# SelectedItem ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Doe anybody know what this means? "Farbe" means colour in German. I'm trying to understand some old code and I can't make sense of this line. `cbModule` is a `Forms.ComboBox`.

```
If IsDBNull(Me.cbModule.SelectedItem("Farbe")) = True Then
```

Comment: It's just checking if the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox` has a field called `Farbe` that is `DBNull`

Comment: @Pikoh you are correct -  you should post an answer, not a comment.

Comment: But there can never be a "Farbe" field, because MS doesn't provide it. The fields are all in English. In other words, there is no "Farbe" field in the Property browser.

Comment: @user2139876 see my answer

Comment: @user2139876 I assume `cbModule` is populate via a `DataSource`? You need to look at that

Answer (score 2):

To understand this, you must first find what's the `DataSource` of the `ComboBox` filled with. I can only guess, but let's suppose it is a `DataTable`, so you'll have something like  `Me.cbModule.DataSource = dataTable`. This makes that all the items of the `ComboBox` are `DataRows`.

So,what you really have in `Me.cbModule.SelectedItem` is a DataRow, that has a column called `Farbe`. This column may contain `DBNull`, so this code:

```
If IsDBNull(Me.cbModule.SelectedItem("Farbe")) = True Then
```

is accessing the DataColumn `Farbe` of the selected `DataRow` and checking if it is `DBNull`.

Hope this make it clear to you and others.